# What is the better of there one liner abominations, and why?

Tags: python

These two functions seem to do the same thing, so what's the point of using getattr?

```
getattr(__import__("os"), "chdir")("/content/")
__import__("os").__dict__["chdir"]("/content/")
```

Comment: Both of them are awful, which should be all you need to know.

Comment: They **do not do the same thing** in Python 3.7

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the `__dunder__` attributes and methods are the implementation details you don't typically want to touch directly (unless you're *implementing* one). To *use* that data you typically use a corresponding function call, which may or may not do exactly the same as if you'd access the attribute directly (typically there are nuances in behaviour that favour the function call, which is why it exists).

Answer (score 1):

`getattr` and `__dict__` are useful only when you need to obtain the value of an attribute whose name you can only obtain at run time. Since in this case you already know that you want a fixed attribute of `chdir`, there's no point of using `getattr` or accessing the `__dict__` attribute. You can instead simply do:

```
__import__('os').chdir("/content/")
```

But then again, since the module you're importing is fixed as well, you should really stick to the normal usage of `import`:

```
import os
os.chdir("/content/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the nastiness of them both, they are **semantically different** in Python 3.7.

- `__import__(some_mdl).__dict__[name]` will find `name` if it has been explicitly defined/assigned in the module;
- `getattr(__import__(some_mdl), name)` will find `name` if it has been explicitly defined/assigned in the module, and if not, *then call `some_mdl.__getattr__(name)` if `some_mdl.__getattr__` is defined*.